# Can't use QWERTY layout after make IBus work with Dvorak layout after reboot

Tags: keyboard-layout, reboot, input-method, ibus

To keep my Input Method (Bogo or Unikey) of IBus working with Dvorak keyboard layout after reboot, I use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` to set keyboard as Dvorak, and go to tab Advance in IBus Preferences to check Use system keyboard layout.

The problem is, sometimes my friends want to borrow my laptop and I can not easily switch to Qwerty layout because any Input Method will use Dvorak. The English - English (US) is the same as English - English (Dvorak) one.

Any idea?

Info: I'm use IBus 1.5.3 and it says this is the newest version. So do Cinnamon.